# How can I simulate a "locked" file (one which has a write lock)

Tags: windows, simulate, filelock

I am trying to debug a problem where users occasionally have locked files which they try to open.  The code appears to have correct exception handling but users are still reporting seeing error messages.  How can I simulate a locked file so that I can debug this myself?

EDIT: For Windows.

Comment: What error messages are they seeing?  Do you know for sure that they have locked files when they get the error message?

Comment: @Ralph, no I don't know if it's a locked file but it seems the most likely.  I was also thinking it may be a file which was accessed over a network which lost a connection.  This is just my first step in debugging.

Comment: Also check to see if there are any intermittent system processes which run during that time which may be locking the folder.

Comment: Some very useful answers to the same question on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/294826/how-to-purposefully-exclusively-lock-a-file), including one to just invoke `notepad > fileToLock` from the command line (though it'll overwrite the file contents of course, but useful for simulating locks).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

depends, but in case, MS word locks
if you are wonderig if your application lock files and it do not relase locks:
just modify a bit your aplication (to create a testapp) and never close the file (and keep it runnig)

Comment: Word or Excel were going to be my suggestions, so an upvote well and truly deserved...  :)

Comment: Luis, thank you for your help.  I will give this method a try.  :)

Answer (score 39):

try this:

```
( >&2 pause ) >> yourfile.txt
```

`>>` opens `yourfile.txt` in *append* mode

see [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for a reference

Comment: I really like this. Is easier than use big MS-Software to lock my file

Answer (score 0):

I used LockFileEx function from the Windows API to write a unittest in Python. This worked well for me (shutil.copy() with a locked target fails).

```
import win32con
import win32file
import pywintypes

p = "yourfile.txt"
f = file(p, "w")
hfile = win32file._get_osfhandle(f.fileno())
flags = win32con.LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK | win32con.LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY

win32file.LockFileEx(hfile, flags, 0, 0xffff0000, pywintypes.OVERLAPPED())
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am using this command prompt

```
type yourfile.txt | more
```

to insert inside `yourfile.txt` a very long text of "few pages" and want to pipe  via `| more` to batch the insertion.
However the file seems to lock, any reason why?