# How can I provoke I/O errors due to locks in a unit test built for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, file-io, file-locking

I have some code that expects to be able to write to a file and I want to test that a couple of error scenarios are handled correctly. One of these is that the target file is locked.

I thought that something like this should provoke the error (in Swift, but that should not matter):

```swift
var someByte: UInt8 = 0b101010

let os = OutputStream(toFileAtPath: "myfile", append: false)!
os.open()
os.write(&someByte, maxLength: 1)

// Inlining methodThatWrites(toFileAt: "myfile")
let os2 = OutputStream(toFileAtPath: "myfile", append: false)!
os2.open()
os2.write(&someByte, maxLength: 1)
os2.close()
// end of inlining

os.write(&someByte, maxLength: 1)
os.close()
```

However, no error happens -- the same process may write concurrently to the same file as it pleases. (Which makes complete sense from the OS' perspective, but is really weird from an application perspective.)

I would try to [start an external process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25726436/539599) and open the file for writing from there, but you can not do that when building for iOS (`Process`, `NSTask` are not available).

Is it possible to simulate a locked file in a unit test built for iOS?

---

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5860542/539599), but the answers don't apply here (no Windows, test is automated).